# Python Tkinter Treeview fixed width with variable SQL query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

Apologies if this was answered before but I cannot find anything out there with these specifics.

I'm finishing a query tool for the team I'm working with where they can choose the fields to query a database and a search a string (along with other options).

The result is being sent to a Tkinter TreeView widget (found this to be the best approach in terms of events control and visualization).

I have a main issue which is to constrain the size of the Treeview to a certain width, no matter how many fields the user chooses. Since the complete GUI is non scalable I want the Treeview to have a max size.

I have tried to include the width when defining the columns, but it seems to bypass that.

The Treeview is a child of a LabelFrame and the positioning is defined with grid.

Here a code sample of what I'm doing to set the TreeView (since this is a company application I have to be careful with disclosing some field names):

```
CoreQuery.groupResults = LabelFrame(CoreQuery.root, text="Query Result", padx=5, pady=5, height=470,width=960)
CoreQuery.tree = ttk.Treeview(CoreQuery.groupResults, selectmode='browse')
CoreQuery.tree.bind("<Double-1>", CoreQuery.OnTreeDoubleClick)

CoreQuery.scrollbar_horizontal = ttk.Scrollbar(CoreQuery.root, orient='horizontal', command=CoreQuery.tree.xview)
CoreQuery.scrollbar_vertical = ttk.Scrollbar(CoreQuery.root, orient='vertical', command=CoreQuery.tree.yview)
CoreQuery.tree.config(height=18, xscrollcommand=CoreQuery.scrollbar_horizontal.set, yscrollcommand=CoreQuery.scrollbar_vertical.set)

CoreQuery.tree.grid(row=0, sticky="w")
CoreQuery.scrollbar_horizontal.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky='ns')
CoreQuery.scrollbar_vertical.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ew')

CoreQuery.scrollbar_horizontal.configure(command=CoreQuery.tree.xview)
CoreQuery.scrollbar_vertical.configure(command=CoreQuery.tree.yview)

CoreQuery.tree.configure(yscroll=CoreQuery.scrollbar_vertical, xscroll=CoreQuery.scrollbar_horizontal)
```

The Following is the method that receives the SQL query result and places the data in the TreeView:

```
    def ScreenPrintResults(header,rows):

        columns=len(header)
        minColumnsize=math.ceil(965/columns)

        #Clear Treeview
        CoreQuery.tree.delete(*CoreQuery.tree.get_children())

        for values in rows:
            values[0] = str(values[0]).replace(".0", "")
            if (values[0].isdigit()):
                values[0] = int(values[0])

        auxCount=0

        CoreQuery.tree['columns']=header

        for value in header:
            CoreQuery.tree.heading(value, text=str(value))
            CoreQuery.tree.column(value, stretch=tk.NO)

        for items in rows:
            if auxCount==0:
                CoreQuery.tree.column('#0', width=30, stretch=tk.NO)
            else:
                CoreQuery.tree.column(value, width=minColumnsize)

            CoreQuery.tree.insert('',tk.END,auxCount+1,text=str(auxCount+1),
            values=list(items))
            auxCount=auxCount+1

        CoreQuery.updateMessage.config(foreground="Black", font="Verdana 10 bold")
        CoreQuery.message.set("...")
```

Is there any kind of limitation I can add the width of the TreeView so that it does not go beyond a certain width? 
Or do I need to split the available width to the number of columns I get from the query?

I honestly don't care if all the information is on screen, hence I placed the scrollbars.

Here is a screenshots of the issue:
[image: Just a few columns]
[image: Expands beyond the interface]

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Changed the For loop code and added more clarifying screenshots of the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate [how-to-set-width-of-treeview-in-tkinter-of-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609865/how-to-set-width-of-treeview-in-tkinter-of-python)

Comment: Issue is solved. It turns out that the column size variable was using fixed width that is basically the width of the application so it would expand beyond that size. So for the Treeview you really need to be careful about the column size.

Answer (score 0):

The example below demonstrate how to set width for the `columns` the `minwith` and `maxwidth` which takes `integers`. Also you can set height of the row using the `rowheight` attribute for your text to display well in the tree.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()


tree = ttk.Treeview(root, column=("col1","col2"), show="headings")

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('my.Treeview', rowheight=50)
tree.configure(style='my.Treeview')



tree.heading("#0", text="COMPANY NAME")
tree.heading("#1", text="DEPARTMENT")
tree.heading("#2", text="BRANCH")

tree.column("#0", stretch=tk.NO, minwidth=100, width=000)
tree.column("#1", stretch=tk.NO, minwidth=100, width=400)
tree.column("#2", stretch=tk.NO, minwidth=100, width=400)

tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("Am using python version 3.6.1 \n on windows machine  ", "This an example Tkinter Treeview in Python, which is from \nttk class make"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("This an example Tkinter Treeview in Python, which is from \nttk class make sure #import ttk\n also from tkinter import *", "Apologies if this was answered before but I cannot find "))


tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did use your code to make a few changes, mostly in the appearing order of heading->column->insert which seems it made it a bit more readable. The issue still stands with the Treeview expanding beyond the LabelFrame and I feel it has to do with the fact that I'm using a for loop to insert rows in the Treeeview. I've added scrollbars but as far as I can see they have minimum size and I can only scroll up/down.

Comment: if it expanding beyond the `labelframe` minimize the width of the `column`